# How can I wrap and unwrap part of an element's text in a span tag in vanilla JS?

Tags: javascript, html

Let's say we have an element

```
<p id="foo">Hello world!</p>
```

And our desired end state is

```
<p id="foo"><span>Hello</span> world!</p>
```

How can we achieve this (as well as do the reverse and unwrap that same text) with pure vanilla JS?

I'm thinking along the lines of...

```
const el = document.getElementById("foo")
const newSpan = document.createElement('span')
//get substring...
el.surroundContents(newSpan)
```

I've read a bit about `surroundContents` and `createRange` and wonder if either are relevant here?

Comment: Did you want to know how to wrap/unwrap any given substring or only the first string of a given element, or...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following way:

**Wrap:**

```js
const el = document.getElementById('foo');
const txtNode = el.firstChild;
const txt = txtNode.nodeValue;

const startIdx = 0; //get the start index
const endIdx = 5    //ending index

const txtBefore = document.createTextNode(txt.substring(0, startIdx)); //the text before
const txtWrapped = document.createElement('span');//create span 

txtWrapped.textContent = txt.substring(startIdx, endIdx);//fill the text
const txtAfter = document.createTextNode(txt.substring(endIdx));//the rest

//replace the element
el.replaceChild(txtAfter, txtNode);
el.insertBefore(txtWrapped, txtAfter);  
el.insertBefore(txtBefore, txtWrapped);
```

```css
p{ color: blue }
span { color: red }
```

```html
<p id="foo">Hello world!</p>
```

**Unwrap:**

```js
const el = document.getElementById('foo');
const spanEl = el.querySelector('span');

const spanParent = spanEl.parentNode;
const txtBefore = document.createTextNode(spanEl.textContent);
const txtAfter = document.createTextNode('');

spanParent.replaceChild(txtAfter, spanEl);
spanParent.insertBefore(txtBefore, txtAfter);
```

```css
p { color: blue }
span { color: red }
```

```html
<p id="foo"><span>Hello</span> world!</p>
```